# recursive rename [mv file01 file0101] [mv file0101 file 01]

Tags: bash, recursion, sed, find, xargs

I really need some help. it should be simple, but I really hit several walls.

@WHY---------------

Well, It shouldn't be the solution to my first problem, but after some research i found easier to do this way.

I'm having a problem with samba and minidlna sharing the same tree directory, because files sent to my router over SMB does not trigger the inotify, and minidlna doesn't rescan media, not showing up in DLNA.

BUT, when I do a ***mv*** I trigger the inotify and minidlna automatically add that file to files.db

@Problems-----------

Im using OpenWRT, so I don't have some commands, like ***rename*** or ***shopt***

My tree its kind of big and large, with spaces.

eg:

/mnt/storage/ANIME/WORLD\ TRIGGER/0056\ -\ The\ Secret\ of\ Lilith\ [1080p].mp4

/mnt/storage/ANIME/WORLD\ TRIGGER/0056\ -\ The\ Secret\ of\ Lilith\ [1080p].srt

@So..------------

What I need is to do a ***mv*** on every single file (and files only, no directories) recursively on /mnt (and the subdirectories) renaming to other name, and then change back to the same name.*

eg:
mv 0057\ -\ Xeno\ and\ Llilith\ [1080p]_**.mp4** 0057\ -\ Xeno\ and\ Llilith\ [1080p]_**.mp4.update**

mv 0057\ -\ Xeno\ and\ Llilith\ [1080p]_**.mp4.update** 0057\ -\ Xeno\ and\ Llilith\ [1080p]_**.mp4**

---

After that I would use it only in the directory where I moved files that is not in the files.db. In the current case, all files in WOLD TRIGGER folder to be faster.

Thank you all for the time to read this.

Comment: Any other simpler way to trigger inotfy would be pretty welcomed. Im starting to find this really heavy for my openwrt. I tried to touch the file and no good.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030